# constraints height is infinity in Row/Column Widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am creating a new custom widget in flutter. 
My requirement is to provide the custom widget constrain as that of the parent widget constraints.

I am facing a little problem here,
When i place my widget inside a container(Parent widget), I am getting proper value for max height and max width like below

```
size = Size(this.constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight);
```

But when i place my custom widget inside a Column or Row Widget . I am getting parent constraints height as Infinity.

When height become infinity i can’t able to render my custom widget. 
Is this the default behaviour in Column or Row widget??
Please find my customWidget code snippet

```
class CustomWigetContainer extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
CustomWigetContainer(
 {
     Widget child
  }): super(child: child);
@override
RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
  return CustomWigetContainerBox();
  }
 }

class CustomWigetContainerBox extends RenderShiftedBox {
 CustomWigetContainerBox() : super(null);

  @override

   void performLayout() {
     child.layout(BoxConstraints(
       minHeight: 0.0,
       maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
       minWidth: 0.0,
       maxWidth: constraints.maxHeight
     ), parentUsesSize: true);

    size = Size(this.constraints.maxWidth, constraints
    .maxHeight); // constraints.maxHeight become infinity when widget is placed inside row/column
   }


 @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    // TODO: implement paint
   super.paint(context, offset);

    final Paint paint = new Paint()
     ..isAntiAlias = true
     ..strokeWidth = 1.0
     ..color = Colors.blue
     ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
     context.canvas.drawRect(new Rect.fromLTWH(50, 20, 100, 200), paint);
     }
   }
```

Comment: By default Container sizes itself depending on the children. Any reason you want to create your own custom widget. Composition is more preferable in flutter world. Any reason you can't compose Container in your widget?

Comment: @ivenxu We are creating a data visualisation widget. By default our custom widget should render based on its parent's height and width.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that is the expected weird behaviour of **Column** or **Row** widgets *along their main axis* because of how the **Box Constraints** are passed down by Column or Row to their children.

In your case, since you are depending on parent's constraint, the children of Column widget will expand to ***infinity height*** because that is the constraint thats passed down by the Column to its children and likewise for Row, children can expand to ***infinity width***. This is likely for responsiveness for different screens.

To understand more, I have written an [article](https://medium.com/@sid.310/flutter-box-constraints-columns-rows-382dcf82256a) on Medium on how box constraint works in general and how they work with Column and Row.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice short article! Finally get why Column and Row are behaving as they do :)

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure you have wrap your custom widget with Container with your favourite size and width before putting into Column .

And Here the code :

```
 home: new Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 150.0,
          width: 120.0,
          child: CustomWigetContainer(
            child: new Text('Hey I am Mir'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

Comment: It is correct answer,
MUST put Widget as child of Container with fixed width or fixed height, will work.